# Для чего нужен prepare в PDO PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Для чего нужен prepare в PDO PHP? Объясните простым языком новичку.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очень хороший вопрос.

### Во-первых, для корректного форматирования данных.

Вот здесь есть [хорошее объяснение](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection), но оно по-английски.

Если коротко, то любые данные, которые попадают в запрос, должны быть корректно отформатированы. Иначе они смогут вызвать ошибку или того хуже - уязвимость.

Причем форматировать данные надо надо обязательно перед самым исполнением запроса - не раньше. Поэтому форматированием должен заниматься сам драйвер для работы с БД, в данном случае - ПДО.

Когда мы передаем запрос в `prepare()`, на место подставляемых данных мы подставляем специальные маркеры. А сами данные передаем после, в `execute()`.

Выполняя запрос, PDO подставляет данные на место маркеров, корректно форматируя их. И таким образом в запросе никогда не будет ни ошибки синтаксиса, вызванной данными, ни - тем более - инъекции.

Поэтому `prepare()/execute()` необходимо использовать всегда, если в запросе используется хотя бы одна переменная.

Примечание. Способы корректного форматирования данных могут быть разными. В частности, в зависимости от настроек, ПДО может не подставлять отформатированные данные сразу в запрос, а отправлять их отдельно. В этом случае при вызове `prepare()` запрос вместе с маркерами отправляется в БД, а данные едут отдельно от него, после вызова `execute()`. В этом варианте данные вообще вообще никак не пересекаются с запросом, а попадают прямиком в БД. Принцип другой, но суть одна - отсутствие ошибок синтаксиса.

### Во-вторых, для экономии ресурсов при выполнении одинаковых запросов.

Также при раздельной отправке можно немного сэкономить ресурсы сервера. В этом режиме можно вызвать `prepare()` всего один раз, а затем только отправлять данные через `execute()`. Таким образом серверу придется парсить запрос только один раз, что немного сократит общее время выполнения запросов. Но особых чудес повышения производительности от этого способа ждать не стоит.

Подставлять ли данные в запрос сразу или отправлять по отдельности, ПДО решает в зависимости от значения настройки `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`.